# Autolayout with stackViews inside a UIPageViewContoller Inside a Container View?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller, uistackview, uicontainerview

I’ve been struggling with this for a few days now…I can’t figure out how to correctly layout these constraints…. the bottom container view on the left is a `UIPageViewController` that loads the VC on the right…. that VC has a background view and 2 stackViews inside it… any ideas on how best to layout? I've tried constraining the leading and top of the background view to the safe area, then the same of the stackview (containing other stackviews) to the background view, but no matter what the stackviews display over each other? [image]

Comment: a side note. Start from your rootview. Get its subviews right. **Then** work on getting the subviews of your subviews at the right place. The reason I'm saying this is _stackviews inside a pageViewController_ has nothing to do with the _UIPageViewController being inside a UIContainerView_. Always try to shrink the size of the problem you're dealing with.

Comment: thank you!  I have indeed tried this, I can get the background view and the top stackView (with the text) displaying without issue, it's when I add the bottom (the graph) it fails to layout correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with auto-layout or my constraints, I was simply trying to fit too big of a view (the graph) inside it's superviews...when I shrunk the size of the graph, the existing constraints laid out the views perfectly.

To anyone else facing a similar issue however, Honey's comment is good advice, generally you should add the furthest "back" view first, add it's constraints, test to make sure it's correct, then repeat on each subview you add, as opposed to dragging all your views, then constraining them.  The former is always the better approach.